# Drupal 10 - Gutenberg Editor undefined

Tags: javascript, drupal, wordpress-gutenberg, hotfix

I'd like to share a bug I had with the Gutenberg Editor in Drupal 10 and also my solution.
Upon installing the editor, on my article edit page I encountered this error:

> `Uncaught TypeError: Drupal.editors[format.editor] is undefined`

I did not understand what to do or how to fix this as my edit page was not loading and the error does not give too much detail on what went wrong. At first I thought it was clashing with CKEditor5 or something, but it turned out to be an easy fix.

**Solution:**

on `/admin/config/development/performance` there is an option to aggregate multiple js files into one in order to save performance. However, there seems to be an issue regarding the order of insertion of the js files, which lead to this problem.

To fix the issue, make sure to unselect the two boxes regarding the aggregation of js files:
[Uncheck the two boxes here and hit save.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0Cq1.png)

Hope this helps! Good luck in the future.

Comment: If you're going to provide a solution, please post it as an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer